# Создания индекса по ограничению (constraint) с тем же именем в предложении создания таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Хочу создать таблицу, с ограничением и одновременным созданием индекса с тем же именем. То есть, в  одном DDL предложении `create table`.

Согласно документации [Oracle 19 SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html) выглядит, что это поддерживается клазулой `using index`.

Запускаю следующий скрипт:

```sql
create table foo (
    id number primary key);

create table bar (
    id     number primary key,
    nick   varchar2 (16) not null constraint bar_nick_uq unique using index,
    foo_id number not null constraint bar_fk references foo using index);
```

Выводит ошибку, что не хватает закрываюшей скобки в последней строке:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Если удалить `using index` после FK ограничения, то работает, но индекс конечно не создаётся.
Для колонки `nick` в примере всё работает как ожидалось, но для уникального, а не для внешнего ключа. Почему так?

Понятно, что можно создать индекс в отдельном DDL предложении, но хочется же, чтобы всё выглядело коротко и понятно.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60436590/6571020

Answer (score 3):

В документации [в подглава: Using Indexes to Enforce Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE) сказано:

> **using_index_clause**
>   You can specify the *using_index_clause* **only** when enabling **unique** or **primary key** constraints.

Пока доступно только для первичного и уникального ключей. При создании таблицы для этих ограничений будет создан индекс для обеспечения уникальности значений, независимо от того, испольуется клазула `using index` или нет.

Для других ограничений создавать индекс сразу вместе с таблицей нет необходимости.

---

Сама по себе клазула `using index` создаст индекс с тем же именем, что и ограничение вместо сгенерированного имени `SYS_C0123456`. Добавив дополнительо параметры или предложение `create index` можно изменить и другие свойства индекса:

```sql
create table bar (
    id     number constraint bar_pk primary key using index,
    nick   varchar2(16) not null constraint bar_nick_uq unique using index (create unique index bar_nick_ix on bar (nick)),
    foo_id number not null constraint bar_fk references foo (id)
);

select index_name, table_name, uniqueness
from user_indexes 
where table_name = upper ('bar');

INDEX_NAME       TABLE_NAME       UNIQUENESS  
---------------- ---------------- ------------
BAR_PK           BAR              UNIQUE      
BAR_NICK_IX      BAR              UNIQUE
```